# Explanation needed on PyTorch 2D convolutional layer

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch

I need explanation on what exaclty goes on in a Conv2d operation in PyTorch.

If I run the following:

```py
import torch
import torch.nn.functional as F

torch.manual_seed(0)

x = torch.randint(20, (1,3,4,4));
y = torch.randint(2, (1,3,2,2));
z = F.conv2d(x,y, stride=1);

print(f"Input: (shape={x.shape})\n")
print(x)
print("")
print(f"Filter/convolutional kernel: (shape={y.shape})\n")
print(y)
print("")
print(f"Feature Map: (shape={z.shape})\n")
print(z)
```

I get:

[image]

Shouldn't the top left entry in the feature map be:

`19+19+6+16+8+18+17=103`?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Turns out my arithmetic was wrong!

`19+19+6+16+8+3+19=90`!